# The definition of normal covering in Hatcher book

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

In page 70 of Hatcher's book, in the section Deck Transformations and Group Actions, the author defines a normal covering in the following way:

> A covering space $p:\tilde X\to X$ is called normal if for each $x\in
> X$ and each pair of lifts $x_1,x_2$ of $x$ there is a deck
>   transformation taking $x_1$ to $x_2$.

Afterwards, the author says this covering of $S^1 \vee S^1$

[image]

is a normal covering, I know why this is a covering, but I didn't understand why this is a normal covering based in this definition.

Please I really need help

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The flipping of the b edges and rotating the diagram by 180 degrees are both deck transformations.

Comment: @Sanchez What do you mean by "the flipping of the b edges"? thank you for your comment.

Comment: Sorry, that part was nonsense. Rotation should be sufficient.

Comment: @Sanchez Sorry, but I still don't understand why this covering in normal according to the Hatcher's definition  :(

Comment: For a generic point of $S^1 v S^1$, what are the lifts?

Comment: @Sanchez let $f$ be a continuous map from a space $Y$ to $S^1\wedge S^1$ the lift $f'$ of $f$ is a map from $Y$ to the covering such that pf'=f.

Comment: I'm not asking about the definition; I'm asking about what the lifts of a generic point of $S^1 v S^1$ to this covering looks like. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Sanchez sorry, I really don't have any idea :(

Comment: OK. In fact, what you said about lifts is slightly off-topic - in this context we are really talking about the preimage of the covering map, where $a$ is sent to the circle on the left of $S^1 \vee S^1$ and $b$ is sent to the circle on the right of $S^1 \vee S^1$. What is the preimage of a generic point of the left circle? What is the preimage of a generic point of the right circle?

Comment: @Sanchez If I understand what you said, the preimage of a generic point in the right circle is a point in the circle in the center of the covering and the preimage of the point in the left circle is two points, one in the right circle of the covering and the second in the left circle of the covering.

Comment: That's right :) Now a normal covering, means that for any two points in the preimage of the same point, there's an automorphism of the covering (called deck transformation), which preserves the covering map and would send one point to another. In this case, it means that for the two preimages in the center of the covering/the two preimages on the left & right of the covering, there's a symmetry of the covering that sends one point to the other point. Is there any symmetry you can think of that does just that?

Comment: I understood just a little bit, tomorrow I will try to solve my doubt again. Thank you very much:)

Comment: @user42912 @Sanchez The latex code for the wedge product is `\vee`.

Answer (score 1):

By proposition 1.39(a) of Hatcher it will suffice to show that

$$H = \pi_1(\tilde{X}) = \langle a,b^2, bab^{-1} \rangle \unlhd \langle a,b\rangle.$$

$\tilde{X}$ is the covering space in your picture above. Now to show normality it will suffice to conjugate each of the generators of $H$ by $a$ and $b$ and see if they're in $H$. Clearly any conjugate of $a$ is in $H$. Any conjugate of $b$ is also in $H$ because $b^{-1}b^2b = b^2$ while $ab^2a^{-1}$ has to be in $H$ because $a$ and $a^{-1}$ are. If you conjugate $bab^{-1}$ by $b$ you get $b^2a(b^{-1})^2$ which is in $H$ because $b^2,a,b^{-2} \in H$ while if you conjugate by $a$ you also get something in $H$ because $a$ is already in $H$.

Hence the covering space $\tilde{X}$ in your picture above is a normal covering space of $S^1 \vee S^1$.

Comment: Is $b $ or $b^2$ in the part "any conjugate of $b $ is also in $H $"?